# Unity 3d Persistent data, Save file doesn't come out as hoped

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, persistence, saving-data

I have recently started with Unity. Currently I'm stuck when it comes to data persistence. While I can create a file, however it doesn't contain the serialized variable. I've already read and seen various tutorials. Unfortunately, I still do not get ahead. I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

This is my **SaveLoad.cs** I could use without editing much:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public static class SaveLoad {
    public static List<Game> savedGames = new List<Game>();

    public static void Save() {
        savedGames.Add(Game.current);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create (Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd");
        bf.Serialize(file, SaveLoad.savedGames);
        file.Close();
    }
    public static void Load() {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd")) {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd", FileMode.Open);
            SaveLoad.savedGames = (List<Game>)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **game.cs** with the (I hope) serialized variable I try to save:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class Game { 

    public static Game current;
    public Click CurrentEuros { get; set; }

    public Game () {
        //CurrentEuros = 1;
        CurrentEuros = new Click();
    }
}
```

The outcome is alway in the last line of the savedGames.gd "Game".

Comment: Unity can't serialize `static` vars; see [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/script-Serialization.html) and [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html). Maybe try making `current` be `public Game`?

Comment: At first, thanks for the links. But when I just erase the "static" everywhere I have to, I get some errors "An object reference is required to access non-static member 'SaveLoad.Save()'".
I guess this happens because the class "File" is already static.

Comment: Instead of the `BinaryFormatter` you can also usne the `XMLSerializer`. That way you can read the savegame. That makes debugging way easier as you see what is saved and create custom save games.

Answer (score 0):

implement ISerializable interface:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[Serializable]
public class PlayerProfile : ISerializable
{
   private string _profileName;
   private string _saveGameFolder;

   public PlayerProfile()
   {
   }

   public PlayerProfile(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   {
      _profileName = (string)info.GetValue( "ProfileName", typeof( string ) );
      _saveGameFolder = (string)info.GetValue( "SaveGameFolder", typeof( string ) );
   }

   public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   {
      info.AddValue( "ProfileName", _profileName, typeof( string ) );
      info.AddValue( "SaveGameFolder", _saveGameFolder, typeof( string ) );
   }
}
```

use it like this:

```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Reflection;
   using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
   using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap;
   using System.Runtime.Serialization;

   PlayerProfile _playerProfile;

   public void SaveProfile()
   {
      //IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      IFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();

      string fileName = "my.profile";

      FileStream stream = new FileStream( fileName, FileMode.Create );
      formatter.Serialize( stream, _playerProfile );
      stream.Close();
   }

   public bool LoadProfile()
   {
      //IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      IFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();

      string fileName = "my.profile";

      if( !File.Exists( fileName ) )
         return false;

      FileStream stream = new FileStream( fileName, FileMode.Open );
      _playerProfile = formatter.Deserialize( stream ) as PlayerProfile;
      stream.Close();

      return true;
   }
```

this is tested and works 100%

you can use BinaryFormatter or SoapFormatter with this code - which ever you prefer